# How to remove lines not ending in a number?

Tags: regex, gvim

How do I null or better yet, remove, the lines in a file that do not end in a number [0-9]?
I'm using gvim

`blahblahblah delete this line`

`foobarbizzbuzz keep this line because it ends in 9999113`

I've tried

`:%s/.+\d+$//g`

`:%s/.+[0-9]$//g`

Message on both versions return `Pattern not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
:v/\d\+$/d
```

Without an explicit range, the `:v` command searches all lines in the buffer and for those lines that *do* *not* match the pattern (in this case, one or more decimal digits at the end of a line), executes the command after the pattern, which in this case deletes the line.